# What's the font in the screenshot?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

Posted in release notes to VSCode editor, I couldn't figure out what's the font. Really like it.

**To Mods**: Sorry for asking off topic question, I flagged myself for deletion.

[image]

Comment: Really not what StackOverflow is for. Google will almost trivially find you https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont and friends; use them. Also as a question specifically about VSCode: just look it up on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: FYI, their issue template specifically links to ask vscode questions not related to bugs/features/regressions here and not on their public github page.

Comment: equally FYI, Stackoverflow has a pretty clear ["what can I ask about here"](/help/on-topic) itself, which takes presedence over any "please ask on stackoverflow" instructions. "Which font is this" is absolutely one of those questions, because as per the ["How do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) you are expected to find the answer yourself first, and this is one of those things you can *absolute* find with google. This didn't need to be a question at all, you were perfectly capable of finding the answer yourself without needing to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font looks like `monaco` to me. But I am not entirely sure.

Kinda looks the same:

[image: Font Display]

Comment: Please just point people to something like https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont in the future. "What font is this" is not on-topic for StackOverflow, and trivially answered by the person asking the question themselves if they take the effort to google for a font identification service. (and in this specific case, this question should have been asked on the VSCode repo, not yere)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So you basically voted down an answer instead of flagging the question as off topic because I gave an answer directly rather than linking to another resource? Yea, makes sense.

Comment: Not "instead": I did both. The question should be closed, and this answer shouldn't be here.

Comment: While I appreciate your effort in trying to make StackOverflow stay on topic, I do think you are putting way too much effort in what a small question about the font. I tried googling before, I found the site you mentioned & it didn't help me much really. I am sorry if my question offended you in any way but as the person mentioned you could've always flagged the question as off topic and go about your day. Have a good day, I will flag the question myself so you can be sure it's not rubbing in your eyes.